# download VSTS artifact without login on Linux

Tags: linux, azure-devops, artifacts

I have setup build/test/release on VSTS. And we have another pipeline (in Linux) to get the build artifact from the build system with a give build id. So is there a way to download the build artifact from VSTS on Linux? I found that you can't download it without login. We used to use Jenkins. It works good as Jenkins doesn't require login for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, authentication is required, you can [create personal access tokens to authenticate access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate).

You also can build a API app to get artifacts with authentication, then another pipeline can get build artifact from that API app.